# Doctrine2 Migration - single table inheritance - parent id does not exist

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I don't get a simple table inheritance to work in my blog.

Here is what I have:

3 simple classes

1. A general abstract Comment Class
2. Subclass for comments made to blog posts with a foreign key to one
3. Subclass for comments on activities also with an foreign key

**General Comment Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperClass
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MY\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\CommentRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog_comment")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap( {"blogentry" = "BlogComment", "activity" = "ActivityComment"} )
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
abstract class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $title;
    ...
```

**Comment for Blog**

```
/**
 * BlogEntryComment
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MY\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\BlogEntryCommentRepository")
 */
class BlogComment extends Comment
{

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MY\BlogBundle\Entity\BlogEntry", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_entry_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
 */
 private $blogEntry;
 ...
```

**Comment for Activity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MY\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\ActivityCommentRepository")
 */
class ActivityComment extends Comment
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MY\BlogBundle\Entity\Activity", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="activity_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
 */
 private $activity;
 ...
```

Building all entities with

```
./app/console doctrine:generate:entities MY
```

*works fine*, this means that super class methods like `getId()` will be automatically be inserted into `Comment` class.

And the only functions inside sub-classes are setter and getter for their own properties like `getBlogEntry()` or `getActivity()`

When I finally try to create a migration to update the database I get:

```
    ./app/console doctrine:migrations:diff -vvv                                                        

  [ReflectionException]                                                    
  Property MY\BlogBundle\Entity\ActivityComment::$id does not exist  

Exception trace:
 () at MY_PATH/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:79
 ReflectionProperty->__construct() at MY_PATH/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:79
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getAccessibleProperty() at MY_PATH/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php:889
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->wakeupReflection() at MY_PATH/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:537
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->wakeupReflection() at MY_PATH/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:209
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() at MY_PATH/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:114
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() at MY_PATH/vendor/doctrine/migrations/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php:68
 Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\DiffCommand->execute() at MY_PATH/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/MigrationsBundle/Command/MigrationsDiffDoctrineCommand.php:49
 Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\Command\MigrationsDiffDoctrineCommand->execute() at MY_PATH/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:252
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at MY_PATH/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:900
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at MY_PATH/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:192
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at MY_PATH/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:96
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at MY_PATH/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:123
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at MY_PATH/app/console:22
```

It will not find the id attribute of the sub class for some reasons.

Changing access levels resulted in faulty code creation. If is set `$id` to `public` or `protected` will break the code generation using task `./app/console doctrine:generate:entities MY`

I know there have been numerous posts about this topic but nothing helped with my problem. I did:

- disabled all cache
- cleared cache every time OR even removed app/cache
- deleted all files and started from scratch
- included `@ORM\Table(name="blog_comment")` inside every sub-class
- tried different access level modifications

Can someone point me to my problem or knows what could possibly causes this. I lost a whole workday on this disgusting problem.

Comment: Actually changing $id visibility to `protected` should help. What error do you have in this case?

Comment: If I change it to protected ``doctrine:generate:entities`` will generate the parents protected fields as private fields inside the child-class. 

This results in ``PHP Fatal error:  Access level to ActivityComment::$id must be protected (as in class Comment) or weaker``. The error will happen appear while ``doctrine:generate:entities``

Comment: The `$id` property is not available in `ActivityComment` or `BlogComment` if it's declared **private** in your abstract `Comment` class - change it to **protected** together with all other properties that should be inherited ! For what purpose did you run `doctrine:generate:entities` again ?! You already have the classes don't you ... why overwrite them ?

Comment: @nifr you are completely right. Don't know why I did re-generate the entities and destroyed the already working code. This and the protected access level solved the problem. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, first of all you must understand, that setting **$id** to `protected` is the only correct solution. That's all.

Doctrine is generating duplicate private **$id** in all child classes, that's true. I had the same issue in my doctrine mongodb project. And as far as I understand it's doctrine bug, and you can nothing to do with that.

You can only remove all extra fields and methods that doctrine generates in child classes after every `generate:entities` command run.

Comment: I think nifr is right, we don't need to regenerate the classes once they are created. This way we can avoid the nasty doctrine bug. 
I'll accept your answer as it's the first. But in general nifr already suggested this in the comments. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @cb0 actually you need to regenerate documents sometimes. For examle, if you do some massive refactoring.

Comment: Ok, in this case it might be needed. I'm happy for now :)